# How to add AAR library to xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, aar

Is there any possibilty to add aar library to xamarin studio? I use xamarin studio on mac and i tried add project based on gradle - caldroid to my project. When i try add aar lib to my project with ProjectLibraryZip properties. I can not use any method from this library i c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add a Java Bindings Library (via Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library template) to your Xamarin solution and add the `.aar` file to the Jar folder in the project tree (`Embedded Jar` Build Action) just as you would a `.jar` file.

That was the easy part, now simply compiling that Library project will cause the generation of a C# wrapper for ALL the classes/methods/enums/consts in that Jar/Aar file. It usually is never *just* that simple as not everything translates cleanly from Java to C# so be prepared to manually write some transformation rules to filter out classes, rename methods, etc.. that are located in the project tree at:

```
├── Transforms
│   ├── EnumFields.xml
│   ├── EnumMethods.xml
│   └── Metadata.xml
```

Xamarin has a good walk through of the entire process, start there:

- [Binding a Java Library Consuming Java libraries from C#](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/)