# Convert aar to DLL library

Tags: c#, android, dll, xamarin.forms, aar

Hi I'm a new in Xamarin development and using Visual Studio 2015. I need to create dll lib so I can use it as Reference for Visual Studio.

I already have an aar file from Android library project. How to generate *.aar file from it? Using Command line would be very good !

Comment: you shouldn't convert aar to dll. You should just connect aar to your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add AAR library to xamarin studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167406/how-to-add-aar-library-to-xamarin-studio)

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko I'm using Xamarin Forms, so I need dll.

Comment: I don't think that you need it, but I might mistake, so try to explain, why you need it?

Comment: @VladMatvienko hi, it's for an Xamarin Forms project and they mainly use dlls and in addition the customer wants a dll

Comment: well, you should know that you will be able to use the code and features from AAR only in Android. So I don't see any reason except that the customer wants dll just because. I think that in process of binding AAR might be converted to DLL, so I still suggest you to try the link I've posted.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I see, however do you know if there is a way to get the AAR to DLL just using command line? Because I want to publish the DLLS on nuget.org and just using one command to get the DLLs will make my life easier.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in order to add  add an .AAR file you can create a Java Bindings Library.  The bindings library creates a DLL that can then be imported into any Xamarin Forms project.  The three main steps are:

1 - Create an AAR file in Android Studio.  To build the .AAR file, right-click on your project name (in my case, messages), then click the Gradle tab on the far left of the screen. Go to Build -> Assemble Release.

2- The next step is to create a bindings library for the .AAR file.   Create a Bindings Library Xamarin Forms Solution.  After creating the solution, right-click on Jars, click Add -> Add Files, and copy the the .AAR file generated in Step 1. Build the project and the .AAR file will be located in the /debug directory.

3 - Import the DLL file into the Xamarin Forms project you would like to use it in.

For more detail, here is a blog post I wrote on it: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/09/25/export-java-xamarin-forms/

Comment: try answering directly here too, links can break

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I expanded my answer!

Comment: I got so many errors in the java bindings projects it says: CS0102 The type already contains a definition for, CS0111 Type already defines a member called with the same parameter types etc.